# Simple query search - OrientDB

Tags: search, nosql, orientdb

I'm new in graph database - OrientDB.

I have a problem to search vertex connected to other vertex with specific edge.

For example: 
I have a database - MovieRatings (public database OrientDB). I want search only Adventure type of movies.

How can I do it?

Thank you for your answer.

[image: Graph database]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select from Movies where out("hasGenera").description contains "Adventure"
```

Hope it helps

Regards